# Holo Calendar crashes when using Calendar.SATURDAY as last day of week

Tags: java, android, calendar, out-of-memory, infinite-loop

I am using [Holo Calendar library](https://github.com/vdesmet93/holo-calendar).

It is a large amount of code, and so I cannot include it in this thread. Hopefully someone will see this who has used it, but the library is free and there is a link at the bottom of the page to a completed project that you can open.

You can set the start and end days of the calendar in the following way:

```
mMultiCalendarView.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
mMultiCalendarView.setLastDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
```

But this is an odd-looking calendar to me. The first day of the week is Monday, and then both weekend days are at the end of the week. I would like to have each week go Sunday-Saturday.

I can set the first day of the week to anything, without problem, but the following line:

```
mMultiCalendarView.setLastDayOfWeek(Calendar.SATURDAY);
```

causes the app to stall out, regardless of the first day of the week. It appears to be in an **infinite loop**, the log cat keeps spitting out similar the following:

```
02-10 20:29:03.876    2143-2143/(appName) I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 96.710MB to 96.000MB
02-10 20:29:03.876    2143-2143/(appName) D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1272K, 8% free 90712K/98260K, paused 45ms, total 45ms
```

until the app crashes with the following memory warning:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

The errors point to the following lines in the library:

```
at com.vdesmet.lib.calendar.CalendarView.createHeaders(CalendarView.java:286)
at com.vdesmet.lib.calendar.CalendarView.initView(CalendarView.java:93)
at com.vdesmet.lib.calendar.AbstractCalendarView.onLayout(AbstractCalendarView.java:397)
```

which are the following lines, respectively:

```
LINE 286:    headers.addView(header);
LINE  93:    createHeaders();
LINE 397:    initView();
```

I apologize that this all means very little without the libraries on hand. I've combed through every line of code, and every loop dealing days of the week, but I cannot figure this one out.

Has anyone worked with this, or does anyone have any thoughts to what's causing the crash (based on the library available at [this Github page](https://github.com/vdesmet93/holo-calendar))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking from the source code, the error seems to be caused by unreachable end condition for `do-while` loop, particularly on [line 288-291](https://github.com/vdesmet93/holo-calendar/blob/master/Calendar/src/main/java/com/vdesmet/lib/calendar/CalendarView.java#L291) inside `createHeaders()`:

```
private void createHeaders() {

    ...

    final int firstDayOfWeek = mFirstDayOfWeek;
    final int lastDayOfWeek = mLastDayOfWeek;

    ...

    int dayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek;

    do {

        ...

        // increment dayOfWeek, make sure it's a valid day
        dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek % 7;
        dayOfWeek++;
    } while(dayOfWeek != lastDayOfWeek + 1);

    ...

}
```

[`Calendar.SATURDAY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#SATURDAY)'s value is 7, not 6 as what the developer expected. (To be exact, it starts from `Calendar.SUNDAY` (1), `Calendar.MONDAY` (2), ... to `Calendar.SATURDAY` (7)).

On the other hand, `dayOfWeek % 7` will only return 0-6, add 1 afterward and you will get 1-7. But the end condition for the loop is when `dayOfWeek == lastDayOfWeek + 1`. When it's `Calendar.SATURDAY`, it's `(7 + 1) == 8`, which is out of range. Thus, the loop won't end, resulting in `OutOfMemoryError`.

The solution is to change the end condition to `while(dayOfWeek != (lastDayOfWeek % 7 + 1));` to make sure that the `lastDayOfWeek` also wrap from 1-7.

**Addendum**

The changes need to be applied on 2 lines inside `CalendarView.java`:

- on `createHeaders()`, [line 291](https://github.com/vdesmet93/holo-calendar/blob/master/Calendar/src/main/java/com/vdesmet/lib/calendar/CalendarView.java#L291):

  ```
  } while(dayOfWeek != (lastDayOfWeek % 7 + 1));
  ```
- on `initView()`, [line 119](https://github.com/vdesmet93/holo-calendar/blob/master/Calendar/src/main/java/com/vdesmet/lib/calendar/CalendarView.java#L119):

  ```
  while((currentDay.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) % MONTHS_IN_YEAR == currentMonth ||
          currentDay.get(Calendar.MONTH) == currentMonth ||
          currentDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != (lastDayOfWeek % 7 + 1)) {
  ```

Credit to [pandes for follow-up on their GitHub's issue](https://github.com/vdesmet93/holo-calendar/issues/2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I figured this out a while ago, but had forgotten I posted this question. And yes, it is all to do with the mod operators in the conditionals. Haven't tested this, but will select as answer, until otherwise proven wrong (but it all sounds about right!).